# Cracking sound on Speaker connected to USB Soundcard

Tags: audio, electronics

I have connected speaker on USB sound Card with PAM8403 Amplifier before speaker to amplify sound on Raspberry Pi Zero W.

[image: Speaker]
[image]

I get constant cracking sound coming from it. I have connected 3.3V as VCC on amplifier.

Can you please tell me why is it coming and how to stop it.

I read somewhere it is because of some ground problem, what exactly is it?

Answer (score 1):

I normally associate "cracking sounds" with static electricity or loose connection. You can confirm that by laying down the circuit and stopping all motion in the vicinity of your build. If the cracking stops, then the cause is mechanical and you will need to see exactly what motion triggers the cracking sound. If the cracking persists, this is not the answer for you.